# How do I configure my system to trust a CA for a specific subset of domains?

Tags: ubuntu, security, ssl, certificate, tls

The company I work for has a number of internal web services accessible over HTTPS. These services use SSL/TLS certificates signed by an internal certificate authority which is only trusted by computers issued by my company. Occasionally, I need to access these services from my personal computer at home. Understandably, this triggers a security warning from my browser. Up until now I've just been ignoring those warnings, but recently I've started to feel a bit uncomfortable about that practice as it leaves my connection vulnerable to man in the middle attacks.

As a solution to this problem, I want to trust the root certificate used by my company on my computer at home. In keeping with the principle of least privilege however, I only want that CA to be trusted for domains my company controls, e.g. *.internal.examplecompany.com. How can I do this? The main computer I am interested in configuring this way is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. (I am also interested in doing this for other devices running Windows 8 and Android, but won't ask about those right now in order to avoid making this question too broad.)

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/q/774930/176688

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There simply is no feature built into standard browsers or SSL clients to allow this.  Basically a CA is either fully trusted, or not trusted at all.

I suppose it may be possible that there is some kind of plugin to allow this, but I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 0):

> Occasionally, I need to access these services from my personal computer at home.

It depends on the software that uses the services. In the case of browsers....

> I want to trust the root certificate used by my company on my computer at home. In keeping with the principle of least privilege however, I only want that CA to be trusted for domains my company controls, e.g. *.internal.examplecompany.com. How can I do this?

You can't. The browser security model (its a real thing) pivots around the CA Zoo, where any CA can certify any site (even if its the wrong CA). There is clearly no interest in changing that model. From [Proposal: Marking HTTP As Non-Secure](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2014Dec/0089.html):

> Open question: do you think the browsers will support a model other
>   than the CA Zoo for rooting trust?

And the answer from the Chromium team [Proposal: Marking HTTP As Non-Secure](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webappsec/2014Dec/0091.html):

> Chromium has no plans for this

Comment: Could you provide a link to more information on the CA Zoo model? Google hasn't been very helpful in turning up information on that for me...